# Facing Error working with Mapsactivity (Newbie)

Tags: java, android, geolocation, maps, currentlocation

iam unable to get my location i dont know why ive tried everything on google as iam a newbie to android please help me solve this

```
package com.parkaspot.najeeb.project;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
final String TAG = "MAIN";
ArrayList<RecentData> list;
RecentAdapter recentAdapter;
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
Drawer result;
Toolbar toolbar;
Double lat, lng;
Location location;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, sharedPreferences1;
String name, password;
SpotsDialog dialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dialog = new SpotsDialog(this,"Loading...", R.style.Loading);

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    sharedPreferences1 = getSharedPreferences("userDetails", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean networkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (networkEnabled) {
        Log.d(TAG,"network is enabled"); //shows successfully
        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {  
            Log.d(TAG,"permission ******************granted"); //This log Tag Never appears in logcat

            return;
        }
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        Log.d(TAG, "Location is initialized"); //shows successfully
    }

    if (location != null) {
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lng = location.getLongitude();
        Log.d(TAG, "getting latlng values"); //**Never shows
    }else{       //******Always returning NULL HERE****
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"location returning null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    list = new ArrayList<>();
    recentAdapter = new RecentAdapter(this, list);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.parkingRecyclerView);
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recentAdapter);

    setUpDrawer();
    init();
}


private void setUpDrawer() {
/*
    final PrimaryDrawerItem item1 = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(1).withName("Home");
*/

    final ProfileDrawerItem profile1 = new ProfileDrawerItem().withName("Najeeb Pasha").withEmail("Najeeb@gmail.com");

    final PrimaryDrawerItem item1 = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Search By Location");
    final PrimaryDrawerItem profile = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Your Profile");
    final PrimaryDrawerItem logOut = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Log Out");
    final PrimaryDrawerItem gps = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("GPS");

    AccountHeader headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withOnAccountHeaderListener(new AccountHeader.OnAccountHeaderListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onProfileChanged(View view, IProfile profile, boolean current) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class));
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .withCompactStyle(true)
            .withHeaderBackground(R.color.drawer1)
            .withCloseDrawerOnProfileListClick(true)
            .withSelectionListEnabled(false)
            .withTranslucentStatusBar(true)
            .addProfiles(profile1)
            .build();

    result = new DrawerBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withToolbar(toolbar)
            .withSelectedItem(-1)
            .withRootView(R.id.drawer_container)
            .withDisplayBelowStatusBar(false)
            .withActionBarDrawerToggleAnimated(true)
            .withCloseOnClick(true)
            .withAccountHeader(headerResult)
            .addDrawerItems(
                    item1,
                    profile,
                    logOut,
                    gps,

                    new SectionDrawerItem().withName("Others")
            )
            .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                    if (drawerItem == item1) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class)
                                .putExtra("url", Constants.getPlaceUrl(lat,lng)));
                    } else if (drawerItem == logOut) {
                        logOut();
                    } else if (drawerItem == profile) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class));
                    }else if (drawerItem == gps) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GpsActivity.class));
                    }
                    return false;
                }


            })
            .build();

}

private void logOut() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.apply();

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = sharedPreferences1.edit();
    editor1.clear();
    editor1.apply();

    recreate();
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignInActivity.class);
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

}


public void init() {
    new Load().execute();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    finishAffinity();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

private class Load extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.show();

    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        System.out.println(Constants.getPlaceUrl(lat,lng));

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                /*.url("http://192.168.0.101/parking/place.php?lat=17.308531&lng=78.5364463")*/
                .url(Constants.getPlaceUrl(lat,lng))
                .build();
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            String responseData = response.body().string();

            System.out.println(responseData);

            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(responseData);


            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                RecentData data = new RecentData(
                        jsonObject.getString("name"),
                        jsonObject.getString("address"),
                        jsonObject.getString("lat"),
                        jsonObject.getString("lng"),
                        jsonObject.getString("distance"),
                        jsonObject.getString("filled"),
                        jsonObject.getString("total"),
                        jsonObject.getString("service"));

                list.add(data);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        dialog.hide();
        recentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

this always returning null please help me from the scratch i dont know how to solve it and iam very very new to android and this is my college homewwork project iam unable to get the loation even with gps or net provider . **please help me with this only this thing then my project will get complete.

> Returning location as Null 
>   Iam a Newbie; 
>   please reply me the whole code with change please.request(Noob)
>   Thank u very much sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get locations, you need to ask for location updates by using the method `requestLocationUpdates(String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener)` on the location manager.

create a listener that will print the data, for example :

```
requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10, new LocationListener(){  
    @Override 
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
        Log.d("LOCATION", location.toString());
    }
});
```

This will ask the location manager to provide me every 1000 ms (1s) and if i moved 10m from the last location a new location.

Comment: where do i add that code iam a newbie can u please help me with it